# Gulp fails with message: object expected

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm trying to use gulp on w7. gruntjs works .. node works ... 
If i start gulp without gulp file, it runs fine .. saying 'no gulpfile found'

gulp -v gives: cli version 3.5.6, local version 3.5.6

installed it using:
npm install -g gulp
npm install --save-dev gulp

If I use the following gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
```

It results in error dialog:

```
Windows Script Host
Line 1
Char 1
Object Expected
800A138F
Microsoft JScript runtime error
```

I did try a more lengthy gulp file, but same error ... by deleting lines, I tried to isolate the problem .. until the file was empty .. that was ok.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here are steps I used to solve that issue:

1. if your tasks file is `gulp.js`, rename it to `gulpfile.js`
2. Install gulp globally `> npm install -g gulp`
3. Test installation `> gulp -v`

You are good if you can see the version number of your gulp task runner!

Comment: gulp was installed correctly. The trick was renaming gulp.js to gulpfile.js ... thanx a million ;-) (Looking back at the documentation, it states it very clear that it should be gulpfile.js ... can't reproduce my reasoning for choosing gulp.js as the filename...)

Comment: @Paul0515 and where the hell did you find THAT nugget... renaming file worked for me as well

Comment: Weird, not sure why I thought the file was to be named 'gulp' - its even in the documentation. How did this many people get this wrong, lol.

Comment: I'm curious as well! How did that end up in the official doco if it doesnt work?!

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a `Microsoft JScript runtime error` it isn't running in node but rather in Windows Scripting Host.  Ensure Node.exe is in your `PATH`.

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion. Node is working fine. I'm using it in the same shell for several things, ... I'm afraid this is not the solution yet. Not anyone experiencing the same thing?

Comment: @robrich, Can you please suggest how to ensure the script should run under Node.exe

Comment: @Praveen_07: ensure that the folder with node.exe is in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: @robrich This is still not the solution. I'm having the `Microsoft JScript runtime error` that you mentioned, however node.exe **is** in my path and NPM works just fine.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: @dxhans5: Windows Scripting Host is before node in the path or you're changing the path as part of execution.