# Why doesn't gulp create files while executing tasks on Windows 8?

Tags: gulp

gulp doesn't create dist directory and files in it while executing tasks

```
gulp.task('css', function () {
    gulp.src('./css/style.css')
        .pipe(stylus({
            'include css': true
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min',
            extname: '.css'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

No errors occur in the console dialog. However everything works fine on linux and mac. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe you need to change the read/write permessions of your windows directories

Comment: Could it be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22692111/1849366 ?